# Is it possible upload file with metadata by storage nestJS sdk?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure storage and Nestjs. I am using Azure storage to store some static files. I can upload files by Nestjs storage SDK successfully.Now I need to upload a file with some custom blob metadata, I have go through the source code of [Nestjs storage SDK](https://github.com/nestjs/azure-storage/blob/master/lib/azure-storage.service.ts), but seems there is no predefined way to do this. So is it possible to upload blobs with custom metadata? Or is there any workarounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have reviewed the source code of `azureStorageService`, it not provides useful methods. But the upload operation replys a storageUrl with SAS token, we could use it to make another HTTP request: [set-blob-metaData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-metadata) to set blob metadata. This is my test code,`name` is the metadata in my test:

```
@Post('azure/upload')
  @UseInterceptors(
    AzureStorageFileInterceptor('file', null),
  )
  async UploadedFilesUsingInterceptor(
    @UploadedFile()
    file: UploadedFileMetadata,
    ) {
      file = {
        ...file,
        buffer : Buffer.from('file'),
        originalname: 'somename.txt'
      };
      const storageUrl = await this.azureStorage.upload(file);
      //call rest api to set metadata
      await this.httpService.put(storageUrl + "&comp=metadata",null,{headers:{'x-ms-meta-name':'orginal name here'}})
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response.status);
      });
   {
    Logger.log(storageUrl);
  }}
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Super! Thanks @Stanley , it works for me.I believe I can do some other operations based on this URL.